# Tooltips not triggered when a window is created/displayed

Tags: winapi, windows-7, com, tooltip

Sometimes when a window is created and visible, it shows as highlighted (orange) in the taskbar. I think this is to notify the user when a window is hidden so they don't miss it (?) but we definitely sometimes see it when programmatically launching an application which *is* visible on-screen.

The problem we then observe is tooltips are not triggered on this window until the user clicks on it, which leads to bug reports that tooltips are not working.

Our applications generally run only one instance but each can display multiple windows, typically created in response to a (D)COM request. e.g. Receipts.exe is a COM application which implements a method `DisplayReceipt(DWORD receiptID)` and each time will launch a new window showing that receipt's details... sometimes the new window appears on-screen un-obscured but without mouse focus, its icon orange in the taskbar.

Is this just a feature of Windows 7 and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Very little information, so I'll have to risk a guess: This programmatically launched application is a *single instance* application, and it contains code that makes this single instance the foreground window ([SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx)). In that case, the following blog entry may be relevant: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can't steal it, it has to be given to you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx).

Comment: See my edit for additional information. Typically you click on a window belonging to Application A and this causes Application B to launch a new window - sometimes that window has focus, sometimes it doesn't.